# Converting SQL varchar column values to $ format i.e. thousand separation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar(256)` column `AttributeVal` with all different type of text values.

I need to find out all $ values like $5000, $2000 etc & add thousand separator to them (only to these values, but not to the other text values present in that column).

Thus the updated values should look like $5,000 & $2,000.

If I am using following query, then it will end up converting all values & I need to concatenate $ manually :(

```
replace(convert(varchar, convert(Money, AttributeVal), 1), '.00', '')
```

NB : I know that these kind of formatting should be taken care in the application end, but our customer is adamant to have these customization to be stored in DB only.

Comment: please post the output in much more meaner way

Comment: declare @t varchar(20)= '$2000'

select +'$'+replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, @t),1),'.00','')

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do a replace statement based on a regular expression like that exactly.  See [this stackoverflow post asking the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql).

You may want to reinforce to your client that formatted data should not be stored in a database.  That money value [should probably be stored in a DECIMAL(13, 4)](https://rietta.com/blog/2012/03/03/best-data-types-for-currencymoney-in/) or something similar instead of a VARCHAR field mixed with other data as well.

Your question is a great example of **why** you don't want to do this.  It makes simple things very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT '$'+ PARSENAME( Convert(varchar,Convert(money,convert(Money, 100000)),1),2)
```

Output: $100,000

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

try with this, this will take care of thousand separator :-)

```
 '$'+convert(varchar(50), CAST(amount as money), -1) amount
```

Sample

```
;with cte (amount)
as
(
    select 5000 union all   
    select 123254578.00 union all
    select 99966.00 union all
    select 0.00 union all
    select 6275.00 union all 
    select 18964.00 union all 
    select 1383.36 union all
    select 26622.36


)
select '$'+convert(varchar(50), CAST(amount as money), -1) amount
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem:

```
select coalesce(cast(try_convert(money, value) as varchar(50)), value) converted
from (
    values ('50')
        , ('5000')
        , ('3000.01')
        , ('text')
    ) samples(value)
```

and the output:

```
converted
--------------------------------------------------
50.00
5000.00
3000.01
text

(4 row(s) affected)
```